# iMacros/Javascript - How to expose text area of recaptcha V2 when in iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, recaptcha, imacros, 2captcha

I have a situation where I need to use 2Captcha to solve recaptcha for the site , but the recaptcha is unusually in its own frame. My normal .js I use in imacros for firefox fails to expose the "text area" to paste the token result into.
How can this be overcome ?Presumably I just need to reference the frame but I am unsure how to do this as I am just starting with javascript and use a script that I paid a coder for . I have asked him but I dont think he is sure , or too busy perhaps !
The code below normally works to expose the text area to input the recaptcha token..

```
macro += "URL GOTO=javascript:((function(){var<SP>k=document.querySelector('[src^=\"https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?\"]').src.split('k=')[1].split('&')[0];document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').style.display='';document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').textContent=k;}))();" + "\n";
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is has been a problem for a long time

Comment: Hey @FadeToBlack, some "stupid" Qt (I hope), did you open "yourself" a parallel Thread today on the 'iMacros' Forum...?: - https://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?p=81729#p81743 - (I am the iMacros Forum Moderator, and the User that opened that Thread on our Forum looks pretty "suspicious" to me, see my Comment on our Forum..., but OK, if it was you, then OK, the Thread is then "legit" and there is no Pb...)

Comment: OK, no Reply..., but I have some "Update" from my side... The User on the iMacros Forum is indeed "fake" and simply C&P'ed your original Post... Their Post will (soon) be deleted, but my Quote/Reply will remain, as your Qt is quite interesting actually... - You can post on our Forum @FadeToBlack if you have an Account or want to register if you want to "take ownership" of that Thread, and you might get some Help on "our" Forum, I don't help myself for 'Captcha' related Threads but we have another Advanced User who maintains one of the Captcha Solving Sites and regularly helps Users...